# Direct Sum In modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

**Definitions:**
$1)$ Let $M_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in I$ be a family of submodules of a module $N$ over a Ring $R$. Then we define the sum of the modules
$$\sum_{\alpha \in I}M_{\alpha}= \{x_{\alpha _{1}}+x_{\alpha _{2}}+...+x_{\alpha _{k}}:x_{\alpha _{i}}\in M_{\alpha _{i}},\enspace\alpha _{i}\in I\;\text{ for }\;1\leq i\leq k \;\text{ and }\; k\in \mathbb{N} \}$$
$2)$ Let $M_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in I$ be a family of modules over a ring $R$. We define the product of modules as
$$\Pi_{\alpha \in I}M_{\alpha}= \{(x_{\alpha}):x_{\alpha} \in M_{\alpha}, \enspace  \alpha \in I \}$$
$3)$ Let $M_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in I$ be a family of modules over a ring $R$. The direct sum of modules is the submodule of $\Pi_{\alpha \in I}M_{\alpha}$ defined as
$$\oplus_{\alpha \in I}M_{\alpha}= \{(x_{\alpha})\in \Pi_{\alpha \in I}M_{\alpha}: x_{\alpha}=0 \;\text{for  all but  finitely many } \alpha \in I\}$$

**Theorem:**
Let $N_{i}$, $i \in I$ be a family of submodules of a module $M$ over a Ring $R$. Then the following are equivalent.
$(a)$ The map $\pi:\oplus_{i \in I}N_{i}\rightarrow \sum_{i \in I}N_{i}$ given by $\pi(\{n_{i}\}_{i\in I})=\sum_{i \in I}n_{i}$ is an isomorphism.
$(b)$ $N_{i}\cap \sum_{j \in I \smallsetminus \{i\}}N_{j}=0$ for all $i \in I$.
$(c)$ Every element $x\in \sum_{i \in I}N_{i}$ can be uniquely written as $x=x_{i_{1}}+x_{i_{2}}+...+x_{i_{k}}$ where $i_{1},i_{2},...,i_{k}$ are $k$
distinct elements of $I$ and $x_{i_{j}}\in N_{i_{j}}$, $j=1,2,...,k$.

**My Question:**
In the Theorem, I suspect that the statement $(a)$ does not hold true due the following reasoning:
 Let $I=\mathbb{N}$
Choose two specific elements from $\oplus_{i \in I}N_{i}$ i.e. $(n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{j},0,0,0,...)$ and $(0,n_{2},n_{3},...,n_{l},0,0,0,...)$.
Now, $\pi((n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{j},0,0,0,...))= n_{2}+n_{3}+0+0+0=0+n_{2}+n_{3}+0+0=\pi((0,n_{2},n_{3},...,n_{l},0,0,0,...))$.

---

Can anyone take a look at it? please help me to understand the above theorem and point out the mistake in my reasoning.

Thanks.

**Note:** Here Modules, means left modules over a Ring $R$ with $1\neq 0$.

Comment: The theorem does not state that a) holds but that a),b) and c) are equivalent.

Comment: @BenediktK If there is a counterexample to the $(a)$, then, $(a)$ won't be equivalent to other two statements.

Comment: Why would $\pi((n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{j},0,0,0,...))$ be equal to $ n_{2}+n_{3}+0+0+0$?

Comment: @Bernard I have used the definition $1$ and $3$, without violating the rules of the definition map $\pi$ (I Think So). If I am wrong can you please help me to understand the part $(a)$?

Comment: @Kumar, you are not using the function $\pi$ properly. $\pi((n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_j,0,0,0,\ldots)) = n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_j$

Comment: @Mike Can You Please explain me $(a)$ and proper use of $\pi$ function?

Comment: @Kumar, the function $\pi$ is simply saying that you sum all the nonzero components in the tuple, as I did above. The reason why you can only have finitely many nonzero elements is because if you had an infinite number of nonzero elements the sum is not defined (you do not need to worry about convergence!). The statement (a) is just saying that the external direct sum is isomorphic to the internal direct sum.

Comment: @Mike But what you are saying, won't it violate the definition $(1)$? If No, Please tell me why?

Comment: @Kumar, I do not understand. As BenediktK mentioned in his response this is a theorem and the theorem is saying that (a),(b),(c) are equivalent (So, if one of these statements is true they all are and if none of them are true none of them are). So, it is not really a matter of violating definition (1). In what way do you think it violates definition (1)?

Comment: @Mike My concern is that for some other problems if I want to use this theorem, I have to show that one of the statements of this holds true for that problem. Moreover, According to definition $(1)$, we can choose any $N_{i}$, but only finitely of them and sum them.

Comment: @Kumar This is true. You do need to show that one of these statements hold to use (a). I assume you are in Dummit and Foote section 10.3. Post any of your solutions and others will take a look to see if you are applying the theorem correctly.

Comment: @Mike Correct, I am reading Dummit and Foote. But This theorem was given by our instructor. In Dummit and Foote, It considers only that if $I$ is finite and I am very comfortable in using it. Difficulty only creeps in for non-finite cases. Surely, I will post my answers for checking. Moreover, I would request you to please put comments as an answer to the question. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Kumar This is true. But, as I mentioned in my previous comment the fact that there are only finitely many components that are nonzero is critical to this argument. I was very confused when I first read the definition of direct sum and direct product and thought that the difference was somewhat superficial. It may help to read something about coproducts in the category of modules to understand this connection a little more (direct sums are coproducts in this category). This can be found in a book like Hungerford's algebra. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the function $π$ properly. $π((n_{1},n_{2},…,n_{j},0,0,0,…))=n_{1}+n_{2}+⋯+n_{j}$.

The function $π$ is simply saying that you sum all the nonzero components in the tuple as above. The reason why you can only have finitely many nonzero elements is that if you had an infinite number of nonzero elements the sum is not defined (you do not need to worry about convergence!). The statement $(a)$ is just saying that the external direct sum is isomorphic to the internal direct sum.